# jetty 9.3 not sending all text messages through websocket

Tags: websocket, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, java-websocket

I have a websocket server based on Jetty v9.3.9
The server sends text messages to clients from different Threads.
A single client can receive multiple simultaneous messages from 2 different threads.
For example:
Thread 1: "message A"
Thread 2: "message B"

Sometimes, not all the times, but around 4-5% of the time, the client doesn't receive all the messages. It receive either message A or B. The client is based on the browser.

I tested in both Firefox and Chrome, and I looked in web console to see if the message is received and is not.

The code I'm using for sending the message is

```
getSession().getRemote().sendString(this.message);
```

from http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.9.v20160517/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/api/RemoteEndpoint.html#sendString-java.lang.String-org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.WriteCallback-

Is this the right way to do this? Should I use `sendStringByFuture(String text)` ? Am I missing something.

On the server I have around 800-1k connected clients, that sends and receives multiple messages from different threads.

NOTE: I used websockets with Jetty since version 8 and I can't remember having this problems until I updated to 9, however I can't go back.

Thank you

Comment: Interesting, when you say "the server sends text messages to clients from different threads" are you meaning multiple threads are using a single Session/Endpoint to send messages?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt yes, I'm sharing the Session object between threads and use session.getRemote().sendString(this.message); to send the message. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: I think my problem is related to this: https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/is_websocket_session_really_thread . Any ideas?

Comment: For whole message (not partial) send using the `RemoteEndpoint.Basic`, each `send()` blocks the calling thread and enters an outgoing message -> extensions -> frame queue.  You should be able to do that scenario easily.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Thanks for you answer. This might sound stupid, but how do I use RemoteEndpoint.Basic ? the method session.getRemote() returns an object that implements org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.RemoteEndpoint . Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using the Jetty WebSocket API or the JSR356 API? (your statements are confusing, and you seem to use the two interchangeably)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116228/discussion-between-doua-beri-and-joakim-erdfelt).